# Strange code Amiga "++[>++++++<-]>.>+"

Tags: decode

Does anybody recognize this?

```
+++++++++++<-]>.>+++++++++[>++++++++++++++
.-------------------------.+++++++++++++
```

I read, that it has something in common with Amiga.
How can I decode it?

Comment: It's not even correct syntax. The braces do not match :)

Comment: The Amiga connection is probably that in 1993 quite a few geeks still had working Amigas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like Brainf*** to me

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BrainF

Probably could look for a compiler and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

It is a ["BrainF*ck"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) programming language. an esoteric programming language noted for its extreme minimalism. It is a Turing tarpit, designed to challenge and amuse programmers, and was not made to be suitable for practical use.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) It was created in 1993 by Urban Müller.

Comment: ...and Urban is the creator of the Aminet.